# Why are backticks returning undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So I'm creating a user search feature for a site but whenever I pass a backtick in React it returns `undefined` I tried casting it into a string, nothing changes.

```
import React, { useRef } from'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faSearch } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

function SearchBox() {
  const searchRef = useRef('');
  var query = `search/${searchRef.current.value}`;
  return (
    <form className="searchContainer" method="post">
      <h1>WAFFLES :D</h1>
      <div className="searchBox">
        <input ref={searchRef} type="text"/>
        <Link className="searchGlass" to={query}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch}/></Link>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default SearchBox;
```

Comment: Are you saying that in `var query = \`search/${searchRef.current.value}\`;` that `query` is `undefined`? Or is it rather that `searchRef.current.value` is `undefined` on the initial render?

Comment: because typing doesn't change the state or props, so nothing happened even typing string into the input, you need to use state to storage the query value, and setQuery once typing things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ref is going to be updated to be the HTMLInputElement, but it looks like your intent is to make the input's *value* update the ref when it changes.

- You need to use `useState` in order to re-render when the value changes; `useRef` will not re-render and update the `to={query}` as needed

```
function SearchBox() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const linkTo = `search/${query}`;

  function handleChange(event) {
    setQuery(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <form className="searchContainer" method="post">
      <h1>WAFFLES :D</h1>
      <div className="searchBox">
        <input onChange={handleChange} type="text" value={query} />
        <Link className="searchGlass" to={linkTo}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} />
        </Link>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle your input in the `onSubmit` like this:

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('SUBMIT', `/search/${searchRef.current.value}`)
}
```

or in the `useEffect` if you're trying to listen for input change:

```
const handleChange = e => {
    const query = `/search/${e.target.value}`
    console.log(query)
}

useEffect(() => {
    searchRef.current.addEventListener('input', handleChange)
    return () => searchRef.current.searchRef('input', handleChange)
})
```

otherwise, I'd recommend @Rose's answer.